# How to contact flask-restful api from react native app?

Tags: python, react-native, axios, flask-restful

i am new to backend dev. I try to developp a flask restful api. I followed the documentation and made the suggested minimal api, that is just returning a jsonified dict. With postman, curl and in the browser, no problem, the api is running and responds to my requests.

From my react native app however, i always get a Netwrok Error.

I tried lots of things:
- multiple IP addresses for the flask serveur
- differents ways to use axios
- different os : win10, ubuntu
- different endpoints : /, /api, /test
- different ways of writing the api (flask-restful class, flask app functions ...)
- manips from web documentations : dev mode of my device, chrome dev tools (port forwarding)
- i asked a react native developper to check my client-side code, nothing wrong according to him,

precisions :
- python code runs under a conda virtual env
- appli runs under node js and expo 
- container folders of my app and my api are at the same level
- the flask server does not respond 404 or whatever, it does not respond at all, the error returned in react native is a network error
- depending on url, the network errors occurs immediately or after a 2 minutes delay
- flask shows requests and status when called by postman, curl, chrome, but does not react when i press my buttons from the react native app

Here is (one of) my python code:

```
from flask import (Flask, jsonify)
# from flask_restful import Resource, Api
from flask_cors import CORS, cross_origin

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)

@app.route("/api", methods=["GET"])
def get():
    return jsonify(hello='bouh !')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=5000, debug=True)
```

and here is the clientside code:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { View, Button } from 'react-native';
import axios from 'axios'; 

import { sharedStyles } from '../../SHARED/_shared';

var url = "http://192.168.1.16:5000/api";

export default class PrevCommune extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.navigation=this.props.navigation;
    };

    getAxios=()=>{
        axios.get(`${url}`).then((response)=>{
            console.log("succes axios :",response);
        }).catch((error)=>{
            console.log("fail axios :", error);
        });
    };

    getFetch=()=>{
        fetch(url).then((response)=>{
            console.log("succes fetch :",response)
        }).catch((error)=>{
            console.log("fail fetch :",error)
        })
    }

    render(){
        return (
            <View style={sharedStyles.mainContainer}>
                <Button onPress={()=>this.getAxios()} title={"get axios"}></Button>

                <Button onPress={()=>this.getFetch()} title={"get fetch"}></Button>
            </View>
        );
    };
};
```

And the lines returned by requests:

```
fail axios : [Error: Network Error]
fail fetch : [TypeError: Network request failed]
```

I saw lots of tutos, videos, articles on flask api but i didn't find where i am wrong. Please tell me if you have any ideas ! I think both client and server codes are ok, the problem seems to be that my requests are blocked by something.

Comment: Hello have you proved the endpoint with post man?

Comment: when i enter the ip address in postman, it gives me the correct answer

Comment: have you configured CORS in your server side? https://flask-cors.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: oh no, i don't Oo i saw cors mentionned in some doc i found but i did not tried ! thank you, i wil try

Comment: well let me know

Comment: for instance, no more results. But cors are required, it is better than before =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved : the probleme was my firewall ... thank you ricardo for the CORS doc =)

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was to change the IP address of localhost to my network IP in the api call in react native and then starting the flask application using the below command.

```
flask run --host=0.0.0.0
```